# Increase font size in R plot

Tags: r, plot, font-size

I'm plotting from a `TermDocumentMatrix` the correlations between all the words. But the font size of the words is so small, I cannot read it.

```
freq.terms <- findFreqTerms(tdm, lowfreq=8)
plot(tdm, term = freq.terms, corThreshold = 0.2, weighting = T)
```

I have tried `cex=1.5` in the plot call as mentioned in other posts but that doesn't anything.

How do you increase the font size?

[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: have you tried `x11(pointsize = 14)` - default is 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with `tm` it's a little different, hence no `cex`:

```
plot(dtm,terms = findFreqTerms(dtm, lowfreq=100),corThreshold = 0.3,weighting = TRUE,attrs = list(graph = list(rankdir ="BT"),node = list(shape = "rectangle",fixedsize=FALSE,fontsize=120)))
```

The key part of that being `fontsize=120` (or = whatever) 
in

```
node = list(shape = "rectangle",fixedsize=FALSE,fontsize=120)
```